# Export HTML Table to Excel file but broken characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel, export

I would like to export my html table to excel.
At first, I tried to use php, but my table may contain 2~3 sql code, so it's a little difficult.
Therefore, I wanna use javascript/jQuery to export it.
It exported successfully, but there's an error - my HTML table contained Chinese but it became broken characters in EXCEL file.
As I open the EXCEL file by notepad, it can show Chinese normally.

↓ script ↓

```
<script>
    //<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function(){
        $("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
            window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('#dvData').html()));
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });//]]>  
</script>
```

↓ HTML and PHP ↓

```
<div id="dvData">
<table rules="all">
    <thead>
        <th width="50"></th>
        <th width="150">登入人數(Login)</th>
        <th width="150">儲值人數(P)</th>
        <th width="150">儲值總和(Sum)</th>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>新玩家(New player)</td>
        <td><?php echo $new1; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $ndata03['data'][0]['count(distinct userid)']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $ndata03['data'][0]['sum(amount)']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>老玩家(Old player)</td>
        <td><?php echo $old1; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $odata03['data'][0]['count(distinct userid)']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $odata03['data'][0]['sum(amount)']; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

How should I modified my code ?